# python method lookup performance in deep hierarchy

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython

The rule python lookups a method is first find in the instance dict then the class dict and then the bases in `__mro__`.

So I suppose look for a method that is very top in a deep hierarchy will respectively expensive. So the experiment code is:

```
class A(object):
    def a(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    pass
...

class Z(Y):
    def z(self):
        pass

def func(inst):
    inst.z
    inst.z()
    inst.a
    inst.a()

from line_profiler import LineProfiler
p = LineProfiler()
p.enable()
instz = Z()
for x in xrange(10000000):
    func(instz)
p.print_stats()
```

And the output is:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                           def func(inst):
     2   1000000       436449      0.4     19.9      inst.z
     3   1000000       652519      0.7     29.8      inst.z()
     4   1000000       428562      0.4     19.6      inst.a
     5   1000000       672929      0.7     30.7      inst.a()
```

The method access to `z` is a bit more expensive than `a`? And the method call of `z` is also barely win.

**So is this indicating that the deep hierarchy is irrelevant to the performance of method lookup?**

Comment: Why are you optimizing for *python 2.7*? Python 2.7 is *dead* and Python 3.6 has countless optimizations that will render all of these results void.

Comment: And no, deep hierarchy *wasn't* irrelevant in Python 2, but most of the time it would be lost in the noise.